# if i add express-handlebars and deploy in render.com i got error

Tags: node.js, deployment, handlebars.js, render.com

I am getting this error

Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  Require stack:

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/express-handlebars.js

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/index.js

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/index.js

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/express-handlebars.js:19:14)

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19) {

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM    requireStack: [

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/express-handlebars.js',

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/index.js',

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/index.js'

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM    ]

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  }

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  npm ERR! errno 1

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  npm ERR! testproject@1.0.0 dev: `node index.js`

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  npm ERR! Exit status 1

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  npm ERR!

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  npm ERR! Failed at the testproject@1.0.0 dev script.

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Apr 6 01:30:19 PM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2023-04-06T08_00_19_233Z-debug.log

if i deploy my node js,hbs application on render

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Cannot find module 'node:events' on Render || Discord.JS V.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75985086/error-cannot-find-module-nodeevents-on-render-discord-js-v-14)

Comment: You'll need to upgrade your node.js on render.com

Answer (score 1):

Write in the console:

```bash
npm install express-handlebars@6.0.6
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 {
   ...

   "dependencies": {

        ...
        "express-handlebars": "^6.0.0", <== add dependency
        ...

        "nodemailer-express-handlebars": "^6.1.0",
        ...
    
      }

    ...
}
```

Comment: `express-handlebars` is already added...