# Error: Cannot find module 'node:events' on Render || Discord.JS V.14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm facing a problem with my Discord.JS V.14 Bot. I use [Render](https://render.com/) as a host. I have a repository of my bot on GitHub and I linked it to Render but when I try to run it (Install Command: `npm install` & Start Command: `node app.js`), it returns this error:

```
==> Starting service with 'node app.js'
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
    throw err;
    ^
  
  Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
  Require stack:
  - /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
  - /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
  - /opt/render/project/src/index.js
  - /opt/render/project/src/app.js
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19) {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: [
      '/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js',
      '/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js',
      '/opt/render/project/src/index.js',
      '/opt/render/project/src/app.js'
    ]
  }
```

`App.js` File:

```js
// import required modules
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const config = require('./config.json');
const startServer = require('./index.js');

console.log(startServer); // make sure that startServer is imported correctly

// create an instance of express
const app = express();

// use body-parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// define routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, world!');
});

// start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || config.port;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

This happens only when I include this line of code here: `const startServer = require('./index.js');`. When I remove it, the console does not return any error and it logs this:

```
  ==> Starting service with 'node app.js'
  Server started on port 3000
```

But it doesn't start the `index.js` file so the rest of the bot remains deactivated! I need a way to launch the `app.js` and `index.js` without returning any errors. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Render uses Node version `14.17.0` by default. However, discord.js v14 requires Node version `16.9.0` or higher.

You can update your `package.json` file with this so render uses a different node.js version:

```js
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.9"
  }
```

Other [ways to upgrade Node on Render](https://render.com/docs/node-version) can be found on the render.com website.